# Unique Cyclic Subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

If we let $$S = \{ e^{q\pi i} : q\in Q   \} $$
Prove that for each $ n \ge 1$ there is a unique cyclic subgroup of order $n$ in $S$ and the union of these cyclic subgroups is $S$. Any help on this?

Comment: Where are you stuck? For example, can you find the subgroup of order 2?

Comment: I think I need more help on understanding what I'm actually looking for and how to approach S

Comment: The elements of $S$ are complex numbers with length one. The group operation is complex multiplication. Look at the subgroup generated by $e^{\pi i}$. What do you get? What about the subgroup generated by $e^{\frac{2\pi}{3}i}$?

Comment: The cyclic subgroup generated by $ e^{\pi i}$ has order 1? And the second one has order 3?

Comment: $e^{\pi i}$ has order 2.

Answer (score 2):

The elements of $S$ are complex numbers. The group operation is complex multiplication and the identity element is $1 = e^{2\pi i}$. So $x \in S$ lies in a copy of $\mathbb Z/ n \mathbb Z$ if and only if it is an $n$th root of unity. We have explicit formulas for the roots of unity. This will prove existence. From the fundamental theorem of algebra, we know there are exactly $n$ roots of unity. This will prove uniqueness.

Comment: That there are at most $n$ roots of any polynomial is true of any field. It does not require the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Answer (score 1):

$S_n = \{ e^{2 \pi i \frac{m}{n}} : m\in \{0...n-1\}    \}$

$(S_n,\cdot)$ is cyclic of order n (you can show the isomorphism with $\mathbb Z_n$)

For the uniqueness use an argument on the generator of the subgroup (show that if $x\in S \ x^n=1$ then $x \in S_n$ )

1)$ \forall n \ S_n\subset S  \implies \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}S_n \subset S$

2)$ x \in S\implies \ x=e^{i \pi q},  q \in Q \implies x=e^{i \pi \frac{m}{n}} \ x\in S_n$ for some n $\implies S\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}S_n$

$1)+2)\implies S=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}S_n$